# Integrate MFA with ADFS with SharePoint FBA authentication, Windows authentication

Tags: sharepoint, adfs, multi-factor-authentication

We have a SharePoint 2016 environment with form-based and windows authentication users. We want to integrate Azure MFA as an additional authentication method for the users. When we try to install Azure MFA on our servers we notice that providing activation on-premise MFA installation is stopped by Microsoft in July 2019.

Any suggestions to complete this would be really helpful for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On-premises MFA server is deprecated in favor of Azure Cloud MFA. Only the existing customers that activated MFA Server before July 1, 2019 can download the latest version, future updates, and generate activation credentials as usual.

You need to federate your SharePoint server with ADFS and configure Azure MFA as authentication provider with AD FS. Kindly check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/configure-ad-fs-and-azure-mfa) for more information.